# Time complexity to find 7th smallest element in a min heap?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am interested in finding 7th smallest element in a min heap, if we assume that min heap contains duplicates ?

I don't know how to approach. Can anyone provide an idea ?

Comment: In case you are interested in the theorey behind this problem, there is an O(k) algorithm to select the k-th smallest element: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540183710308 So it can be done in O(1)

Comment: @NiklasB. I know that, but what if duplicates are there ?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. The algorithm described in that paper only assumes a partial order. Not saying it is practical in any way though

Comment: Do you want the seventh smallest element, or the seventh smallest value? IOW, if the values in the heap were [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...], would you want the seventh element (`5`), or the seventh unique value (`7`)? If it is the latter, then the algorithm @NiklasB. refers to won't work, but your question as written is misleading.

Comment: In addition to @rici's comment, if you want the seventh unique value, it seems like you can get no better than linear time

Comment: @rici, check this please http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures-heap-question-8/ . It says "If Min-Heap is allowed to have duplicates, then time complexity becomes Θ(Log n)." ?

Comment: geeksforgeeks.com is wrong about Θ(Log n)

Comment: @MattTimmermans, It is always O(1), right ?

Comment: yes.  When duplicates are allowed the 7th smallest element is O(1), and the 7th smallest unique value is O(N)

Comment: @MattTimmermans, Just one more doubt. If elements in min heap are 11111111222233334567 . Then 7th minimum is still 1 and 7th distinct minimum is 7. right ?

Comment: @Willturner: There is a huge difference between "the seventh smallest element" and "the seventh smallest value". Suppose you lined up 1000 people by height. It's clear who the seventh shortest person is; you just count from the short end to seven. But finding the seventh smallest height (say, rounded to centimeters if you don't believe two people can have exactly the same height) is much more difficult. When you say, find the seventh smallest element, I assume that's what you want; not the seventh equivalence class according to the heap's comparison metric. GforG makes the same error, imho.

Comment: @rici, then according to you what will be the values for both ?

Comment: @Willturner: Refer to my earlier comment, unless you mean to ask what will be the complexity of the two operations. It is abundantly clear that finding the kth smallest unique value is O(n) since you might have to look at all `n` values (and even then you might not find `k` distinct ones).

Comment: @rici, yes thanks I got for distinct one . But I am still confused for 7 th minimum value ?

Comment: @willturner: it's O(1), because 7 is a constant. See deinst's answer. GforG says this, too. If you wanted the k'th element in an N-element heap, the best answer is more difficult although you can trivially do it in O(k log N) with k delete-min operations. See the paper referenced in Niklas B.'s first comment.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, the cost of finding the seventh smallest unique element is *at least* O(n), but the naive solution (remove elements until you find seven  unique values) would be O(n log n). Maybe it's not even possible in O(n).

Comment: @rici, okk now I got the difference. Its still O(1) whether duplicates are there or not . but for 7th distinct, its O(n). Thanks for helping me !

Comment: @rici, use a hash table  for storing the elements and using a counter we can get 7th distinct min. In O(n), if you can use some auxiliary space. Otherwise O(nlogn ) is best.

Comment: @Willturner: How? I can see how you would do that if you can use the hashtable while you are building the heap, but if you could do that then you could easily avoid putting duplicate values into the heap in which case you go back to the cost of finding the seventh smallest value being O(1). If the heap already exists, though, I don't see how you would use the hash table to improve the naive algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125659/discussion-between-willturner-and-rici).

Comment: @rici It's definitely possible in O(n*k), you just keep a list of the k smallest unique values

Comment: @niklasb: true, and if `k` is constant, that is O(n). Another solution for which the heapness of the `n` objects is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

As the seventh smallest element is in the top 7 levels of the min-heap, it is the 7th smallest of the 127 elements in the top 7 levels.  Since this number is fixed (independent of the size of the original heap), the complexity is O(1).

Comment: (or the 6th smallest of the 126 elements in the second through the seventh level, since the first element is always the smallest.)

Comment: @deinst,  check this please,  quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures-heap-question-8 . It says "If Min-Heap is allowed to have duplicates, then time complexity becomes Θ(Log n)" ??

Comment: @deinst, Check this please http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures-heap-question-8/ .  It says "If Min-Heap is allowed to have duplicates, then time complexity becomes Θ(Log n)"  ??

Comment: @Willturner, This is a difference between element and value.  I have trouble seeing an O(log n) solution for finding the seventh smallest value.  The seventh smallest element could end up on the bottom level, and you'd have to look through O(n) things to find it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple O(k*log k) algorithm to select the k'th smallest element from a heap:

```
# h = input heap
q = new min-heap()
q.insert(h.root)
for i := 1 to k - 1
    top = q.delete-min()
    q.insert(top.left)
    q.insert(top.right)
report q.top
```

Of course this is constant time for the case k = 7. If you want the k-th smallest *distinct* element, rather than the k-th smallest overall, you will need linear time, because all elements in the heap could be equal except for the leaves, and then you need to find the (k-1)st smallest leaf, which is not possible in o(n) if all inner nodes have the same value.